# Apache <if> directive leads to Vary: header entry

Tags: apache, header, vary

I am using a

```
<If "%{HTTP:X-Some-Header-here} == 'yes'">
    // Set some magic here
</If>
```

in my Apache (2.4) config.

This leads to a an "automatic" entry in the Vary: response header (if the stuff within the  section applies) like

```
Vary: other stuff,X-Some-Header-here
```

Is there any simple way to deactivate this behaviour sine the X-Some-Header here is kind of "private" in my config?

I could do some magic with header rewriting but I hope there is a very simple directive to disable Apache to do this automatically.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use req_novary.

As stated in the [apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html):

> req_novary: Same as req, but header names will not be added to the Vary header

Vary header is automatically applied for the following headers:

- HTTP_ACCEPT
- HTTP_COOKIE
- HTTP_FORWARDED
- HTTP_HOST
- HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION
- HTTP_REFERER
- HTTP_USER_AGENT

In your case, this would be something like:

```
<If "%{req_novary('X-Some-Header-here')} == 'yes'">
// Set some magic here
```

Note for RewriteCond you can also use the NC flag